# Division of a pandas data frame without the same length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to do an division of two different data frames.

They have the same column name and number, but the length is different.

The division consists in divide **each value** of this data frame:

**df1**

```
      2017-06-01    2017-06-02  2017-06-05  2017-06-06  2017-06-07
INDEX                   
   0    82449.0     -177507.0   -421443.0    70893.0     -122562.0
   1    95634.0      13662.0     25806.0     253506.0     211002.0
   2   -40956.3     -24179.4    -214666.0    68121.9      66225.6
   3    22950.0     -4590.0     -30600.0    -1530.0      -61200.0
   4   -18608.0      211408.0    284360.0   -88744.0     -64328.0
   5    73830.2      38480.7     21186.9    -68776.2      8437.9
   6   -69682.0     -4080.0     -263273.0    124479.0    -1728.0
   7    11869.0      137352.0    249828.0   -114608.0    -32129.5
   8    36384.6      4565.4      256868.0   -129041.0     89649.0
```

By **each** of this:

**df2**

```
        2017-06-01   2017-06-02   2017-06-05     2017-06-06   2017-06-07
 INDEX
    0   51970500.0   52246700.0   52021600.0     51928400.0   52090500.0
```

*Example: df1[0][0] = df1[0][0] / df2[0][0]*

Comment: To clarify, do you want column-wise division? Such as:
`df1[0][0] = df1[0][0] / df2[0][0]`,
`df1[0][1] = df1[0][1] / df2[0][0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default axis (columns) for the division gives you what you want:

```
df1.div(df2.loc[0])
Out: 
       2017-06-01  2017-06-02  2017-06-05  2017-06-06  2017-06-07
INDEX                                                            
A        0.001586   -0.003397   -0.008101    0.001365   -0.002353
B        0.001840    0.000261    0.000496    0.004882    0.004051
C       -0.000788   -0.000463   -0.004126    0.001312    0.001271
D        0.000442   -0.000088   -0.000588   -0.000029   -0.001175
E       -0.000358    0.004046    0.005466   -0.001709   -0.001235
F        0.001421    0.000737    0.000407   -0.001324    0.000162
G       -0.001341   -0.000078   -0.005061    0.002397   -0.000033
H        0.000228    0.002629    0.004802   -0.002207   -0.000617
I        0.000700    0.000087    0.004938   -0.002485    0.001721
```

which is same as

```
df1 / df2.loc[0]
```

Note that I used `df2.loc[0]`  to extract it as a Series which allows broadcasting. If both of them are DataFrames, both the indices and the columns will be aligned. If one of them is Series, either columns or indices will be aligned.